# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Не запускается скрипт в Pycharm (Всё исправно работает, если переключить на 2.7):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\python.exe" 
C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Python2.7TEST/edu3.py
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\__init__.py", line 123
    raise CodecRegistryError,\
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Current thread 0x00000d80 (most recent call first):
```

Comment: В переменные среды удалил C python 27 и все заработало.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас третий Питон пытается использовать библиотеки от второй версии, видно по-умолчанию в системе она прописана. При установке 2 и 3 версии Питона, они используют одни и те же переменные среды `%PATH%` и `%PYTHONPATH%`. Для того чтобы не было проблем, можно временно переменные менять, например из командной строки:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.5;%PATH%
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
```

Или устанавливать переменные с помощью скрипта, при запуске Питона, или использовать [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher)

В документации [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) подробно описано.